# What should I be testing for in my Django API tests?

Tags: django, api, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

I have started to write an API using the Django REST Framework. I am struggling to think about what tests I should be writing.

My ideas so far are...

- Authentication: making sure users are logged in
- Authorisation: checking users have the correct permissions
- Response body: making sure all the desired fields are present
- Allowed HTTP methods: making sure that users can't perform unintended actions.

Since the Django REST framework uses Django's underlying permissions system, is it really necessary to test permissions at *both* the model level and the API level? In this regard, it seems like some of my tests are testing for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

One of the more important things to test in an API is that it handles requests correctly.  Good requests and Bad ones.